Stimulus module loading incorrect paths only in production
I have a simple Rails app running locally in development on my work machine and in production on Digital Ocean managed by Hatchbox. I have added my first Stiumulus controller ("char_counter") and it works great in development. In production, however, the module isn't loading correctly.
In my /config/importmap.rb, the following line was automatically added when I set the project up using importmaps:
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"

I can see the controller module in my rendered source code:
[…]
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    […]
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-FILEHASH.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-FILEHASH.js",
    "@hotwired/stilulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-FILEHASH.js",
    "controllers/char_counter_controller": "/assets/controllers/char_counter_controller-FILEHASH.js"
  }
}</script>
[…]
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/turbo.min-FILEHASH.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus.min-FILEHASH.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus-loading-FILEHASH.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/controller/char_counter_controller-FILEHASH.js">
<script type="module">import "application"</script>
<script src="/assets/turbo-FILEHASH.js" type="module"><!-- This line shows only in production, not development. -->
[…]

In the browser network inspector for the development page, I can see the loaded controller JS file with a status of 200:

In production, I can also see the same JS file loading correctly with a status of 200, BUT after this I see two failed GET requests treating the application and char_counter_controller scripts as HTML page requests which 404 because they don't match an expected Rails route:

Why is this additional request being made? It results in errors in my browser console and is presumably the reason that the Stimulus controller isn't doing anything in production:

